# Face Recognition for Android

Tags: face-recognition

I have implement face recognition using **opencv**. 
I want to compare face on running camera with online image url then i want result both are same or not.

Would welcome inputs on how to go ahead with the above requirement ..

Comment: What did you do to achieve this? Show your code/efforts here.StackOverflow is not a code writing service. If you have a problem with your code, please provide Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: can you please give me your email id @ShubhamVerma

Comment: can you please provide your email id? i didn't get your id from your profile. i want to send you project on your emailid